# I am currently receiving the attached warning in a "View" in mySQL, any idea what this means?

Tags: mysql, view, mariadb

[Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwOYg.png)

Error: Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: "

The structure of my "View" is as follows:

```
# | Name    | Type
1  id1       varchar(255)
2  id2       varchar(255)
3  category1 varchar(255)
4  category2 varchar(255)
5  category3 varchar(255)
6  id2name   varchar(255)
7  date1     date
8  date2     date
9  name1     varchar(255)
10 name2     varchar(255)
11 name3     varchar(255)
12 category4 varchar(255)
13 level1     int(11)
14 level2     int(11)
15 levelflex  varchar(255)
16 category5  varchar(255)
17 category6  varchar(255)
18 category7  varchar(21)
```

SQL Code:

```
SELECT
`x`.`id1` AS `id1`,
`x`.`id2` AS `id2`,
`x`.`category1` AS `category1`,
`x`.`category2` AS `category2`,
`x`.`category3` AS `category3`,
`x`.`id2name` AS `id2name`,
`x`.`date1` AS `date1`,
`x`.`date2` AS `date2`,
`x`.`name1` AS `name1`,
`x`.`name2` AS `name2`,
`x`.`name3` AS `name3`,
`x`.`category4` AS `category4`,
`x`.`level1` AS `level1`,
`x`.`level2` AS `level2`,
`x`.`levelflex` AS `levelflex`,
`x`.`category5` AS `category5`,
`x`.`category6` AS `category6`,
`x`.`category7` AS `category7`FROM
(
    (
    SELECT
        `r`.`id1` AS `id1`,
        `d`.`id2` AS `id2`,
        `m`.`subcategory` AS `category1`,
        `n`.`subcategory` AS `category2`,
        `r`.`category3` AS `category3`,
        `d`.`id2name` AS `id2name`,
        `r`.`date1` AS `date1`,
        `d`.`date2` AS `date2`,
        `r`.`name1` AS `name1`,
        `r`.`name2` AS `name2`,
        `r`.`name3` AS `name3`,
        `r`.`category4` AS `category4`,
        `r`.`level1` AS `level1`,
        `d`.`level1` AS `level2`,
        `d`.`level1flex` AS `levelflex`,
        `r`.`category5` AS `category5`,
        `r`.`category6` AS `category6`,
        CAST(
            rank() over(
            PARTITION BY `r`.`id1`
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN
            `m`.`subcategory` = `n`.`subcategory` AND `r`.`level1` = `d`.`level1` THEN 1 WHEN `m`.`subcategory` = `n`.`subcategory` AND `r`.`level1` = `d`.`levelflex` THEN 2 WHEN `m`.`subcategory` <> `n`.`subcategory` AND `r`.`level1` = `d`.`level1` THEN 3 WHEN `m`.`subcategory` <> `n`.`subcategory` AND `r`.`level1` = `d`.`levelflex` THEN 4
        END,
        `d`.`date2`,
        `r`.`id1`
            ) AS CHAR CHARSET utf8mb4) AS `category7`FROM
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    (
                                        `Server`.`table1` `d`
                                    JOIN `Server`.`table2` `r`
                                    ON
                                        (
                                            `d`.`category4` = `r`.`category4` AND(
                                                `d`.`level1` = `r`.`level1` AND `r`.`level1` <> 12 AND `r`.`level1` <> 13 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(`d`.`levelflex`, ',', 1) = `r`.`level1` AND `r`.`level1` <> 12 AND `r`.`level1` <> 13 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(`d`.`levelflex`, ',', -1) = `r`.`level1` AND `r`.`level1` <> 12 AND `r`.`level1` <> 13
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                JOIN `Server`.`table3` `p`
                                ON
                                    (
                                        `d`.`id2name` = `p`.`newid2name` OR `d`.`id2name` = `p`.`oldid2name`
                                    )
                                )
                            JOIN `Server`.`table4` `m`
                            ON
                                (
                                    `p`.`newid2name` = `m`.`id2name` OR `p`.`oldid2name` = `m`.`id2name`
                                )
                            )
                        JOIN `Server`.`table5` `h`
                        ON
                            (`r`.`category3` = `h`.`category3`)
                        )
                    JOIN `Server`.`table6` `f`
                    ON
                        (`r`.`id1` = `f`.`id1`)
                    )
                LEFT JOIN `Server`.`table7` `e`
                ON
                    (`f`.`id1` = `e`.`id1`)
                )
            JOIN `Server`.`table8` `n`
            ON
                (
                    (
                        `r`.`date1` >= `h`.`subdate1` AND `e`.`subdate1` = `h`.`subdate1` OR `f`.`subdate2` = `h`.`subdate1` AND `r`.`date1` < `h`.`subdate1`
                    ) AND `h`.`id2name` = `n`.`id2name`
                )
            )
        LEFT JOIN `Server`.`table9` `z`
        ON
            (
                `d`.`id2` = `z`.`id2` AND `r`.`id1` = `z`.`id1`
            )
        )
    WHERE
        `z`.`id2` IS NULL
) `x`LEFT JOIN `Server`.`table10` `y`ON
(
    `x`.`id2` = `y`.`id2` AND `x`.`id1` = `y`.`id1`
)
)WHERE
`y`.`id2` IS NULL
```

The query also takes about 15 or more seconds for a total of 44 rows. Is there any way to optimize this?

I am also trying to transfer data from the view to a table. Any suggestions for this?

SHOW CREATE TABLE:

| View | Create View | character_set_client | collation_connection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sampleview | CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dbadmin`@`%`SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW`sampleview`AS select`x`.`id1` AS `id1`,`x`.`r... | utf8mb4 | utfmb4_unicode_ci |

EXPLAIN SELECT ...:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | derived2 | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 251497948917600 |  |
| 1 | PRIMARY | y | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 | Using where; Using join buffer(flat, BNL join) |
| 2 | DERIVED | d | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 106 | Using temporary |
| 2 | DERIVED | f | ALL | PRIMARY | NULL | NULL | NULL | 115 | Using join buffer(flat,BNL join) |
| 2 | DERIVED | e | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 767 | Server.f.id1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | DERIVED | r | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 767 | Server.f.id1 | 1 | Using where |
| 2 | DERIVED | z | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
| 2 | DERIVED | p | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 140 | Using where; Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join) |
| 2 | DERIVED | m | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 198 | Using where; Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join) |
| 2 | DERIVED | n | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 198 | Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
| 2 | DERIVED | h | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 3759 | Using where; Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join) |

Comment: Edit to include the full SQL, and the full error message as text.

Answer (score 0):

With 251 *trillion* rows, I suspect the query includes an unintended "cross join".  Check all the `JOIN` both in the `VIEW` and in the use of the `VIEW`.

Also, be aware of the precedence rules between `AND` and `OR`.

`OR` is generally a performance killer.

(Meanwhile, I don't see any clues about error 1292.)

Some of these composite indexes may help:

```
y:  INDEX(id2,  id1)
r:  INDEX(category4)
d:  INDEX(category4)
m:  INDEX(id2name,  subcategory)
n:  INDEX(id2name,  subcategory)
p:  INDEX(newid2name,  oldid2name)
h:  INDEX(category3,  subdate1, id2name)
f:  INDEX(id1,  subdate2)
e:  INDEX(id1,  subdate1)
z:  INDEX(id2,  id1)
```

Part of the performance benefit is that most of them are "covering".  For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the underlying tables and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`

Comment: Thanks, Rick. I've added the SHOW CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN SELECT...

Comment: I added some more.

Comment: I will look into it, Rick. Thank you very much for your help. I can't cast a vote at the moment but I will upvote yours when I do.